# ArrayStoreException making a post using apache httpasyncclient

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpasyncclient

Actually client resides in tomcat 8080 & REST API resides in 9090. The URL's will be different when it moves to higher environments. I don't see a call happening to the REST API with  httpasyncclient. I copied the code from Apache website
https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/examples.html

Not sure, how to make the call successful even though I receive an Exception in response

```
CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
    try {
        client.start();
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.addProperty("username", "username");
        obj.addProperty("password", "password");



        String serverURL = "http://localhost:9090/project/api";

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(serverURL);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8");
        params.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        postRequest.setEntity(params);

        Future<HttpResponse> future = client.execute(postRequest, null);
        HttpResponse response = future.get();


    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

I didn't find any useful information on fixing this. Any help would make my day

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler
    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DefaultCookieSpecProvider.create(DefaultCookieSpecProvider.java:93)
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:133)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepareRequest(MainClientExec.java:520)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepare(MainClientExec.java:146)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient.execute(CloseableHttpAsyncClient.java:91)
```

javadocs say

> Open Declaration java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException Exception
>   thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted
>   by throwing an exception. This exception can be inspected using the
>   getCause() method.

Answer (score 0):

The most probably reason - conflicts in `httpclient` version. F.e. project dependencies include `httpclient` and `httpasyncclient`. `httpasyncclient` has transitive dependency for another version of `httpclient`. As the result project dependency has 2 incompatible versions of `httpclient`. One of such case with detailed explanation is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49898063/4651234