# Elasticsearch Rest Client throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException

Tags: java, elasticsearch, rest-client

I am using Elasticsearch Rest Client v5.5.3 to execute Elasticsearch queries in a Java application. It always throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException. First I suspect frequency of query execution since application intensively executes queries but it throws exception very first query. Second I update some dependencies like Apache HttpCore.jar which Elasticsearch rest client uses. But either way I could not figure out how to solve it still throws exception. Stack trace is below;

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler
    at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DefaultCookieSpecProvider.create(DefaultCookieSpecProvider.java:92) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:152) ~[flux-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132) ~[flux-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepareRequest(MainClientExec.java:520) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepare(MainClientExec.java:146) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:124) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141) ~[httpasyncclient-4.1.2.jar:4.1.2]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:343) ~[rest-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:325) ~[rest-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:218) ~[rest-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:191) ~[rest-5.5.3.jar:5.5.3]
    at com.nova.stats.platform.are.batch.rule.ElasticsearchQueryExecutor.execute(ElasticsearchQueryExecutor.java:36) [classes/:?]
```

The method executes queries;

```
public String execute(String query, QueryParameters parameters) throws IOException {
        String index = (String) parameters.getParameter(GlobalConfigurations.ElasticsearchConfigurations.ConfigurationFields.INDEX);
        String type = (String) parameters.getParameter(GlobalConfigurations.ElasticsearchConfigurations.ConfigurationFields.TYPE);

        RestClient restClient = ElasticsearchRestClient.getClient();
        HttpEntity entity;
        Response response = null;
        try {
            entity = new NStringEntity(query);
            response = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/" + index + "/" + type + "/_search",
                    Collections.singletonMap("pretty", "true"), entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Could not perform request, query: " + query, e);
        }

        String responseStr = responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


        return responseStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem description**

The problem root cause is "JAR Hell" due to conflicts `httpclient-4.5.2` and `flux-core-1.1.0`. I don't know why but `flux-core-1.1.0` jar contains inside full httpclient codebase version 4.3.3 which is not compatible with 4.5.2.

What is `ArrayStoreException`, Javadoc quote:

> public class ArrayStoreException extends RuntimeException Thrown to
>   indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of
>   object into an array of objects. For example, the following code
>   generates an ArrayStoreException:
>          Object x[] = new String[3];
>          x[0] = new Integer(0);

In version httpclient-4.3.3 `RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler` looks like

```
@Immutable
public class RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler implements CookieAttributeHandler {
```

In version httpclient-4.5.2 `RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler` looks like

```
@Immutable
public class RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler implements CommonCookieAttributeHandler {
```

And the problem in `DefaultCookieSpec` which tries to invoke constructor of `RFC2965Spec` of version 4.5.2 with `RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler` from 4.3.3, which in not implements `CommonCookieAttributeHandler`:

```
RFC2965Spec(final boolean oneHeader,
            final CommonCookieAttributeHandler... handlers) {
    super(oneHeader, handlers);
}
```

**Solution**

The most probably reason of "JAR Hell" - your `pom.xml` (or gradle) has dependency for `httpclient-4.5.2`. You should remove it from dependencies or downgrade to `4.3.3` version. Also your `pom.xml` may have dependency for `httpasyncclient-4.1.2` - in this case you also could remove it from dependencies or downgrade to `4.0.x` version. At worth your project could have transitive dependency for `httpclient` or `httpasyncclient` - in such case you need to find and fix it.

Comment: There is also another solution if for some reason you can't change dependency or it is not convenient to do. You can have the same library in two different versions in your code if you use [shading](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) or [fat-jars](https://forgegradle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/shading/) on problematic dependency. Probably overkill in this case, but it's still worth to mention it as one of the solutions.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Whatever I did to exclude dependencies from flux-core it did not work. I used exclusion for dependency tag and used shade to exclude package from dependency. None of them worked

Comment: You cannot exclude something from `flux-core` because it's a single jar containing classes from `httpclient`. Try to find out which components also has `httpclient` as dependency. F.e. with `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=httpclient` for Maven.

Comment: Elasticsearch rest client (v5.5.3) has httpclient dependency. I think I should find a way to exclude from apache storm flux-core since I cannot downgrade version of Elasticsearch rest client.